# Question about potential race condition with ParallelStream of Lists

Tags: java, java-stream

I came across this piece of code that uses Java streams, specifically parallelStream() in order to collect some data from an oracle database. See below where in this case:

- range = some list of input Id
- rangeLimit = 1000
- rangeLimitedFunction = some function that queries a DB for some content

```java
ForkJoinPool threadPool = new ForkJoinPool(Math.min(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), parallelism));

try {
    Optional<C> res = threadPool.submit(new Callable<Optional<C>>() {
        @Override
        public Optional<C> call() throws Exception {
            return splitByLimit(range, rangeLimit).parallelStream()
               .map(rangeLimitedFunction::apply)
               .reduce((list, items) -> {
                   list.addAll(items);
                   return list;
               });
        }
    }).get();
```

From what I understand this is how this is working:

1. Split range into chunks of 1000 to feed into the function
2. Process each chunk in a thread to return some results
3. Aggregate the results to a list of POJOs

My question is around a potential race condition imposed by trying to reduce into a single list. Is it not possible for many of these threads to be trying to add content to the resulting list and potentially corrupt data?

Comment: Where did you come across this code? I ask because it involves the "hack" to run a parallel stream inside a custom ForkJoinPool instead of the common pool, yet as Nicktar said it really doesn't make sense to write code like that to read from a database.

Answer (score 3):

That depends largely on the implementation of List that's used in this case.

That said, this pice of code would be way better using `flatMap` and a `collector` to leverage the thread-safety of Java paralell streams and avoid potential pitfalls from non-thread-safe list implementations.

That said, paralellStreams don't offer much benefit for IO-operations. They target processor heavy operations and usually only pay-off if there are more than 15000 (IIRC) operations (that is stream-iterations times cpu-heavy stream operations), which is kind of rare.

Comment: The implementation is a linkedList in this case. And from what I've read there are definitely more appropriate implementations, just trying to understand what we have before proposing a change